yGuard configuration for public library (JAR) in gradle kotlin-script
I am building a library (JAR) in kotlin, which should be obfuscated.
There is (for the moment) one class and one method which should be able to be called from outside.
To obfuscate i would like to use yGuard and gradle (kotlin)
My build.gradle.kts yGuard configuration looks like:
...

configurations {
    create("yguard")
}

...

dependencies {
...
    "yguard"("com.yworks:yguard:4.1.1") // obfuscation
...
}


tasks.register("obfuscate") {
    dependsOn(tasks.jar)
    group = "yGuard"
    description = "Obfuscates the java archive."

    doLast {
        val archivePath = tasks.jar.get().archiveFile.get().asFile.path
        val unobfJar = archivePath.replace(".jar", "_unobf.jar")

        ant.withGroovyBuilder {
            "move"("file" to archivePath, "tofile" to unobfJar, "verbose" to true)

            "taskdef"(
                "name" to "yguard",
                "classname" to "com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask",
                "classpath" to configurations["yguard"].asPath
            )

            "yguard" {
                "inoutpair"("in" to unobfJar, "out" to archivePath)

                // Prevent yGuard from removing "Deprecated" attributes from .class files.
                "attribute"("name" to "Deprecated")

                "rename"("logfile" to "${projectDir}/build/${rootProject.name}_renamelog.xml") {
                    // Obfuscation settings
                    "keep" {
                        "method"(
                            "name" to "boolean doProcess()",
                            "class" to "my.x.y.ProcessUtil"
                        )
                    }
                }
//                "shrink"("logfile" to "${projectDir}/build/${rootProject.name}_shrinklog.xml") {
//                }
            }
        }
    }

The class:
package my.x.y

class ProcessUtil(
    private val param1: Object,
    private val param2: Object,
) {

    fun doProcess(
       private val paramX: Object
    ) {
       ...
    }
}

This configuration runs successful, but everything is obfuscated to package names like A.A.A and so on.
I am stuck on how to define the class and method in the "rename" and/or "shrink" section to obfuscate all of the code except the one class and method.
Unfortunately can't get the understanding out of the documentation of yGuard.
Any hints and help are appreciated!

I found a solution how to configure yGuard to exclude the one method in a class:
            ...
            "rename"("logfile" to "${projectDir}/build/${rootProject.name}_renamelog.xml") {
                "keep" {
                    "class"(
                        "name" to "my.x.y.ProcessUtil",
                    )
                    "method"(
                        "name" to "boolean doProcess()",
                        "class" to "my.x.y.ProcessUtil"
                    )
                }

            }
            ...

